problems starting HADOOP-3.4.0 in ubuntu-64
Im trying to start hadoop on mi VC. yesterday it was functioning without a problem until my computer "aborted". When I restart it and tried using hadoop I couldnt so I downloaded again.
Now, when I try to start it it says this:
/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-3.4.0/sbin$ ./start-dfs.sh
./start-yarn.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [vagrant]
2024-12-02 11:51:20,076 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
and if I try to access it I have this error
$ hdfs dfs -mkdir /test
$ hdfs dfs -ls /
2024-12-02 11:40:56,015 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: Call From vagrant/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
2024-12-02 11:40:56,931 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
ls: Call From vagrant/127.0.1.1 to localhost:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
I downloaded again but I still have the same problem.... any idea what to do?
alongside hadoop i hava JAVA-8u431
I tried everything I and chatGPT coukd think of (-_-')
